# What does 自己师 means?

Tags: translation

I’ve found an interview and there is question that I have no idea what it's mean, the question is “什么时候发现自己师的”

I try to understand but not sure. Does it mean “When did you learn by yourself” or something?

Answer (score 1):

师 is probably just a typo of 帅, handsome.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably a mistake,mostly its 帅 which means have a good looking